# What should I do to play Legacy StarCraft with my brother on my own computers over LAN?

Tags: battle.net, starcraft

This question is a follow-up question of [Do I need two licenses to play StarCraft 2 multiplayer over a LAN?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/12982/75209).

### Constraints

1. My internet connection is unstable for online game so I have to play a LAN game. I choose Legacy StarCraft rather than StarCraft 2 because I think the former provides playing over LAN.
2. I want to play with my brother using my 2 computers, one for me and the other one for my brother. My computers have Windows 7 installed.

### Questions:

1. Is it allowed to purchase and download a single Legacy StarCraft installer from my Battle.net account and install it on both of my computers mentioned above?
2. If it is not allowed because of licensing issue, should I just purchase 2 licenses from my Battle.net account but  just download the installer once? Downloading the installer twice seems to be inefficient, does not it?
3. Or do we need to have a separate Battle.net account each and just buy and download the installer separately via each Battle.net account?

Comment: We can't answer legal questions. We're not lawyers. What I believe StarCraft offered was a "spawn" copy on the install disk. It would only allow multiplayer, and no cd-key was needed. Dunno if that's part of the digital copy, though.

Comment: So I have to contact a lawyer before purchasing it.

Comment: If you want to know if its legal or not, yeah.

Comment: @Frank: But technically the program can be played simultaneously (LAN mode) on both computers with the same game key?

Comment: If you want some fun custom games to play with your brother, here's a great site that will let you download them: http://sc.nibbits.com/maps/browse/?p=&sort=downloads&order=desc&

Comment: StarCraft 2 Arcade is free, and you can play StarCraft 1 through the Arcade. I know you are worried about your internet issues, but at least it's free.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starcraft 1 (Or legacy Starcraft) does not have a Battle.net registration included to play on local.

As Frank said, we are not lawyer, so we won't answer legal questions.

However, you **can** play with the same CD-KEY on two different computers in multiplayer via LAN (TCP-IP).

For the installation issue, you just have to download it once, install on both computers with the same CD-KEY. This will work because nothing restraints you on the number of computers you want to install your game on.

The CD-KEY part is only to proceed an installation and connect to "old" Battle.net. (Only one instance of the same CD-KEY could be logged on at a time) This is actually not what you are trying to achieve and therefore not your problem.

Hope this helps! Enjoy a game of this Epic never-getting-old game!